# Error Resource not found even the resource exists

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I uploaded some blobs into a container of my Azure Storage account. Now I am trying to access those blobs in the browser.

For that, I found the blob URL in its properties section. When I copied that URL and ran it in a new tab, I am getting `Resource Not Found` Error detailed below

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>ResourceNotFound</Code>
<Message>The specified resource does not exist. RequestId:***** Time:2022-08-18T8:16:16.7201850Z</Message>
</Error>
```

What to change??? Is this something related to permissions or access policies or RBAC role??

Comment: Containers are private by default. You'd either have to create a public container / blob, or generate a SAS (shared access signature) to allow for temporary access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error as below:***

[image]

The error usually occurs if the **`access level`** of your container is Private.

**To resolve the error,** change the **`access level`** to **Public** and try running the URL in the browser like below:

[image]

***After changing the access level, I am able to access the Blob like below:***

[image: ![enter image description here](https://i.imgur.com/4JsRKRt.png)]

Comment: So, go to `Storage Account's` container, select your `container`, and click row end ellipsis icon, then select `Change access level`, it will be by default private, change it to `Blob (anonymous read access for blobs only)` and done, refresh you image or resource will be fetched.